# Problema con al actualizar valor datetime en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema con un valor tipo datetime ya que no puedo hacer un Update en BD debido a un campo de tipo datetime ya que veo que la tabla todos los registro tiene un formato de tipo yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 y el valor que le estoy pasando a mi campo me trae un valor Feb 23 2022 6:51PM, no se como hacer para que tenga el mismo formato de yyyy-mm-dd, el campo lo quiero actualizar con la fecha actual(hoy)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo sql

```html
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_BuscaReactivar]
 @Cadena nvarchar(max),
 @Opcion varchar(100),
 @Mensaje varchar(250) OUTPUT

 as
 Begin

    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX); 
    DECLARE @fecha datetime=CAST(GETDATE() AS datetime)

IF @Opcion='Actualizar' 
    BEGIN
         SET @Query = 'UPDATE CNR_HHH SET resultado=0,'+CONCAT('fecha_habilitar=',@fecha)+', fecha_ejecucion='',descripcion_transaccion='' WHERE CONSECUTIVO in (' +  @Cadena + ')'
         EXECUTE (@query)
        SET @Mensaje='Exito'
        select @Query
    END
 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, el dato `datetime` no tiene formato, internamente es simplemente un número, el formato es algo que se aplica a cadenas. Ahora bien, para actualizar de la forma que lo estás haciendo, básicamente escribiendo una cadena literal para la fecha, deberías (a) encerrar las fechas con comillas simples (2) usar un formato ISO.

No necesitas "castear" la fecha, ya es un `datetime`

```
DECLARE @fecha datetime = GETDATE()
```

La actualización en todo caso debería ser así:

```
+ 'fecha_habilitar = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fecha, 121) + '''' +
```

Estamos usando la función [`CONVERT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) y el formato 121 ODBC Cannonical para construir una cadena con un formato que es interpretado adecuadamente por el compilador de la consulta

Por último tengo que mencionar, que concatenar los valores en una consulta no es una buena práctica, no en este caso, pero en otros, puede ser fácilmente un vector de inyección de código malicioso. Es mucho mejor trabajar con [`sp_executesql()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) y los datos pasarlos directamente como parámetros en la llamada, por ejemplo  `fecha_habilitar = @fecha`